# Create 'SharePoint Solution' programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, creation

I found something related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153916/create-blank-solution-files-for-vs2010-programatically) but did not give me a good start

[image]

Since recently I do a lot of webPart development I want to automate the none-code part of the process, I want to develop a small console app that creates SharePoint solution as the pic, i'll use it as a template for the upcoming webParts

assume the webpart name is a var
`string webPartName = "usefulLinks";`

- Create Empty SharePoint Project
- Add Visual WebPart `webPartName`
- Create Classes Folder `WebPartName`
- Create an empty class inside the folder
- add the `Layouts` mapped folder
- add `css` and `img` folders to the `layouts` folder
- Change part of the `.webpart` content to custom values
- Same to the `Elements.xml` file
- add the `Resources` mapped folder and add two resources files for `Arabic` and `English`
- and finally change the `feature` name to be like `webPartName + Feature`

any good starting points? or online resources

thank you.

Comment: The bounty you have placed won't do anything for the fact that I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are really describing is a custom SharePoint Solution **Project**, not a Visual Studio solution.

> Project templates provide the files that are required for a particular project type, include standard assembly references, and set default project properties and compiler options.

[This section in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx) covers how to create project templates for Visual Studio. In particular, it sounds like the best option for you is the **["Export Template Wizard"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527343.aspx)**, which will create a template based on an existing project you have created.

Comment: the `Export Template Wizard extension` works just fine, but regarding `How to: Substitute Parameters in a Template` still vague for me, Couldn't locate any files related to `.vstemplate` the only file that schema-like this is `SharePointProjectItem.spdata`inside the `layout` folder and don't think its related to this matter, anyway I changed its content as article says but nothing helped, I'll be appreciated if you give me hand on this, Thanks.

Comment: @Rami.Shareef you need to be more specific than "I followed the tutorial and it doesn't work."

Comment: ok, to be more specific --> Q: how to use custom parameters in the `Export Template Wizard extension`? any references would be great